# Use hashing to find a subarray of strings with minimum total length which contain all the distinct strings in the original array

Tags: java, arrays, string, algorithm, hash

Hi this a java exercise on hashing. First we have an array of N strings (1<=N<=100000), the program will find the minimum length of the consecutive subseries which contains all distinct strings which present in the original array.

For example, original array is {apple,orange,orange pear,pear apple,pear}

the consecutive subarrays can be {orange, pear, pear, apple}

so answer is 19

I've written a code which visit every element in the array and create a new hash table to find the length of the subarray which contain all the distinct strings. It becomes very very slow once N is larger than 1000. So I hope there is a faster algorithm. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! This could be interesting problem for some algorithm lover, but the question in my opinion in its current form is somewhat difficult to understand and they might just skip the opportunity. When you say "the consecutive subarrays can be ..." are you missing {apple,orange,orange,pear}? You could also explicitly define what you mean by minimum length (sum of the lengths of each array elements, it seems).

Comment: @FooF From the answer 19, it seems the minimum length is the total number of characters in the series.

Comment: Your question could be understood just as "How man different strings are in the original array?" Because it is nowhere required AFAICS that the said subarray must **actually appear** in the original array, just that such a subarray exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Pass through the array once, using a hash to keep track of whether you've seen a word before or not. Count the distinct words in the array by adding to your count only when you're seeing a word for the first time.
2. Pass through the array a second time, using a hash to keep track of the number of times you've seen each word. Also keep track of the sum of the lengths of all the words you've seen. Keep going until you have seen all words at least once.
3. Now move the start of the range forward as long as you can do so without reducing a word's count to zero. Remember to adjust your hash and letter count accordingly. This gives you the first range which includes every word at least once, and can't be reduced without excluding a word.
4. Repeatedly do the following: Move the left end of your range forward by one, and then move the right end forward until you find another instance of the word that you just booted from the left end. Each time you do this, you have another minimal range that includes each word once.

While doing steps 3 and 4, keep track of the minimum length so far, and the start and end of the associated range. You're done when you need to move the right end of your range past the end of the array. At this point you have the right minimum length, and the range that achieves it.

This runs in linear time.

Comment: @Trying The OP wants the minimum letter count. Also I think a description of an algorithm is more useful to learning than code.

Comment: @DaveGalvin Thank you very much! I finally passed all my test cases. But I realised for step 3 and 4, not only I should check from left to right, I also need to check from right to left(reverse the array and check again) to get the answer.

Comment: @user2982578 Can you give an example where you need to reverse to catch a case?